# How to get the index of the score from the stored array in game in ios using parse table.

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my gaming application, I have scored all the scores of friends, facebook id, name in the array. I have compare my score with friends score and get the rank of my score. How can i do that using objective c code??

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far, don't ask for the "entire code".

Comment: if (scoreArray2.count==0) {

        isNewHighScore = YES;

        NSLog(@"You create new high Score.");

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"HighScore%ld",(long)[GameStatus sharedState].levelNumber ]] ;

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

   if (score>storeScore) {

               [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:i forKey:@"position"];

               NSLog(@"i got  %d position in between my friend",i+1);

               if (i==0&&i==1) {
//print first and second rank
}

Comment: Could you edit your question and put these lines in, for everybody's sake?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
..
NSArray *allScores = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12],
                                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:43],
                                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:5],nil];

int myScore = 44;
int myPosition = [self myPositionForScore:myScore inAllScores:allScores];
NSLog(@"myPosition: %i", myPosition);
..


- (int)myPositionForScore:(int)myScore inAllScores:(NSArray *)allScores
{
   NSArray *sortedScores = [allScores sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

   for (int position = 0; position < [sortedScores count]; position++) {

       if (myScore <= [[sortedScores objectAtIndex:position] intValue]) {
           return position + 1;
       }
   }

   return [sortedScores count] +1;
}
```